# Если убрать слово, как изменится пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация, тавтология

> Я остановилась почти в центре храма и как только первые впечатления от
>   его великолепия чуть улеглись, как две фигуры, расположенные
>   симметрично, в простенках между капеллами, над резными исповедальнями,
>   оказались настолько разными, что обратили на себя моё внимание.

В правильном ли направлении я мыслю, товарищи?

*Я остановилась почти в центре храма, и только первые впечатления от его великолепия чуть улеглись, как две фигуры, расположенные симметрично, в простенках между капеллами, над резными исповедальнями, оказались настолько разными, что обратили на себя моё внимание.*

Но теперь мне мешают  *только... как*!

Поможите, люди добрые, сироте...

Comment: Первое "как" было явно лишним. "Только... как" мне совсем не мешает; перегруженностью отсылок к дому Джека мешает "как... , что". Можно изменить концовку так: "... показались мне удивительно разными, сразу обратив на себя моё внимание."

Comment: Пока впечатления не улеглись, фигуры "не оказывались", а как только улеглись — "оказались"(?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызывает сомнение  переход: ....**и только** первые впечатления  **улеглись**, как две фигуры **оказались** ...

Поэтому предлагается **такой вариант**:

Я остановилась почти в центре храма,  и  только первые впечатления от его великолепия немного улеглись, как мое внимание привлекли две фигуры,   расположенные **симметрично**, в простенках между капеллами над резными исповедальнями, **но  при этом совершенно разные**.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Тогда другой вариант:

Я остановилась почти в центре храма, и только первые впечатления от его великолепия чуть улеглись, как две фигуры, расположенные симметрично, в простенках между капеллами, над резными исповедальнями, **показались мне настолько разными, что привлекли к себе внимание.**

Comment: Все, на мой взгляд, идеально, кроме одной спорной детали. Были ли фигуры  **совершенно** разными? Возможно, вернее сказать "сильно отличающиеся друг от друга"?

Comment: Мне первый варинат все-равно больше нравится, почему бы не завершить его так: "две фигуры, расположенные симметрично, в простенках между капеллами над резными исповедальнями, но при этом сильно отличающиеся друг от друга"?

Comment: А "сильно отличаться" - это общелитературный стиль? Может быть, "значительно/заметно отличающиеся друг от друга"?  В то же время редактор не любит вносить существенные изменения в текст, ну да выберет что-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, так:
Я остановилась почти в центре храма, и первые впечатления от его великолепия чуть улеглись. Две фигуры, расположенные симметрично в простенках между капеллами, над резными исповедальнями, оказались настолько разными, что обратили на себя моё внимание.

Или так:
Я остановилась почти в центре храма, и первые впечатления от его великолепия чуть улеглись. Две фигуры, расположенные симметрично в простенках между капеллами, над резными исповедальнями, обратили на себя моё внимание — они оказались разными!

Мне кажется, что запятую после "симметрично" можно не ставить.

Answer (score 1):

Я остановилась почти в центре храма, и, когда первые впечатления от его великолепия чуть улеглись, две фигуры — в простенках между капеллами над резными исповедальнями, казавшиеся ранее собственными отражениями, — вдруг сделались такими совершенно разными, что обратили на себя моё внимание.

Comment: А что изменилось (освещение, положение наблюдателя), благодаря чему они вдруг стали разными?

Comment: Кто ж знает. Она остановилась, стало быть до этого она передвигаясь оценивала интерьер в целом — в силу своего интереса и воспитания, оставляя детали на потом. И даже если знала храм дистанционно и всё доподлинно об этих личностях, увиденным лично она бы восхитилась.

Comment: Две ситуации. (1) Она не замечала, что они разные, а потом заметила. Слова "стали разными" не подходят. (2) Они казались ей одинаковыми, но что-то изменилось (освещение, например)   — и они "стали" (в переносном смысле) разными. Я думаю, автор описывает первую ситуацию, но неверно подбирает слова.

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант:

**Я остановилась почти в центре храма, и(,) как только первые впечатления от его великолепия чуть улеглись, оказалось, что две фигуры, расположенные симметрично, в простенках между капеллами над резными исповедальнями, были настолько разными, что обратили на себя моё внимание.**

Он стилистически хуже, чем предложенный Jasmin, но максимально близок к авторскому тексту.

Comment: "Оказались и оказалось" не очень подходят к ситуации. Из словаря: ОКАЗАТЬСЯ. 4. Предстать, явиться на деле, в действительности каким-л., кем-, чем-л. 5. безл. Стать явным, очевидным. А какое здесь значение? Вроде бы "показалось" больше подходит, так как продолжает ряд впечатлений.

Comment: Да, все плохо, непрофессионально. Мне нравится только "мое внимание привлекли две фигуры", как в Вашем,первом варианте.  Даже ценой существенных изменений в тексте.

Comment: Да, хотелось бы знать, какой будет окончательная редакция.